# Exclude dates from date calculation

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I'm looking to calculate the time in between 2 dates. I've been using [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter), which works great for outputting properly in all languages/regions/calendars.

I'd like to add the ability to exclude weekends from this calculation. It doesn't seem to support this natively. Is there a good alternative (native or 3rd party libraries) to remove a set of dates from the calculation?

Comment: Why not use `Calendar` to iterate the range between your two dates, skipping weekends? You can add up those ranges and pass the resulting `TimeInterval` to `DateComponentsFormatter` to format.

Comment: What does "to remove a set of dates from the calculation" even mean? Don't you just want to count the intervening weekend days and subtract that number of seconds? Give an example of possible input and desired output, please.

Comment: Why do you think that it does not support natively? You will have to go through calendar date related api to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this type of calculation natively using the `Calendar` API; you're just going to have to write it manually:

```
import Foundation

// The nextWeekend API is available only on 10.12 or later.
if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let start = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 3, day: 18))!
let end   = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 4, day: 7))!

var total: TimeInterval = 0

// We'll iterate weekends from now until the target end date,
// adding the intervening time from during the week.
var current = start
while current < end {
    guard let weekend = calendar.nextWeekend(startingAfter: current) else {
        break
    }

    if weekend.start > end {
        // Our target end date is before the next weekend; add whatever time is left.
        total += end.timeIntervalSince(current)
        break
    } else {
        // There's >= 1 weekend between now and the target date; add the week in between.
        total += weekend.start.timeIntervalSince(current)
        current = weekend.end
    }
}

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = .day
print(formatter.string(from: total)!) // => 16d

}
```